# Confused with CSS: image button with hover tooltip and image changing when hover

Tags: html, css

I understand the basics of CSS.In fragments.

I try  to understand how to combine all of what I want together.
I want to create two types of buttons, "*view*" and "*save*".
I have 4 images, two for each, where one represents the button, and one when mouse hovers it.
So I want an alternative background when hover.

I want also a tooltip, something "*cheap*" like "*View file*", "*Save file*", that better explains the content of the image if it wasn't clear enough.

I understand that I need to use the hover attribute, background attribute, and somehow to create a tooltip.
Those two buttons are actually images with a link
How do I combine it all together?

Comment: What have you got so far? Show some css that you currently have that's not doing it for you?

Answer (score 1):

you could do something like this:

```
<div title="View File" class="view-button">
    View File
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.view-button {
    background-image: url("first-view-image");
}

.view-button:hover {
    background-image: url("second-view-image");
}
```

And the same for the save button. The `title` tag shows a small tooltip. if you want bigger/fancier tooltips, you have to use some javaScript framework.

Comment: Jquery Tool-tip will help through it, just follow the example : http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Answer (score 1):

check this out

HTML

```
<button>Hello</button>
```

CSS

```
button {
    background: url(your-image.png) no-repeat;
}

button:hover {
    background: url(your-image-hovered.png) no-repeat;
}

button:focus {
    background: url(your-image-focused.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi i've created a fiddle for you. When you hover the image/button changes and also you get a small tooltip that says "Click here to Save". Is that all you need? Tell me if this helped you or you have any questions.

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/erKt8/)**

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="save" title="Click here to Save"></a>
```

CSS

```
            .save {
             margin-bottom: 10px;
             width: 47px;
             height:20px;
             display:block;
             background:transparent url('http://www.mtsworld.com/images/button_submit.gif') center top no-repeat;
            }

            .save:hover {
               background-image: url('http://www.ecdoe.gov.za/ecdoe/graphics/buttons/submit.png');
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my example, change background value to your image, to use tooltip i used jqueryui
[Example](http://cdpn.io/iDasw)

html

```
<a href='#' class='button savebutton' title='Save form'>Save</a>
<a href='#' class='button cancelbutton' title='Cancel action'>Cancel</a>
```

css

```
.button{
  background : #999;
  padding : 5px 10px;
  border-radius : 5px;
  color:#fff;
  text-decoration : none;
}
.savebutton{
  background : blue;
}
.cancelbutton{
  background : orange;
}

.savebutton:hover{
  background : cyan;
}
.cancelbutton:hover{
  background : yellow;
}
.ui-tooltip {
  padding: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  max-width: 300px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #aaa;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #aaa;
}
body .ui-tooltip {
  border-width: 2px;
}
```

JS

```
$('.button').tooltip();
```